# Why does scrollintoview() behave differently on desktop and mobile?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am using the `scrollIntoView()` function in a vanilla JavaScript project I have. One thing I have noticed is that the behavior on desktop and mobile browsers is completely different even though I use the `{ behavior: "smooth" }` option. On phones is it extremely fast that you cannot even see the scroll whatever browser I use.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "desktop" and "phones"? For example, Safari (both on desktop and mobile) does not support [`scrollIntoViewOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility, https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView already …?

Comment: Yes I did all the checks. The issue is just the behavior whereas on safari, opera, firefox, chrome and yandex on mobile the scrolll is really quick whereas on the same browsers on my laptop you get a smooth scroll. Was just wondering why.

Comment: Every browser on iOS is forced to use the WebKit engine under the hood. As a consequence, no browser on iOS supports smooth scrolling at the moment.